# Spring data elastic search findAll with OrderBy

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring data's elastic search module, but I am having troubles building a query. It is a very easy query though.
My document looks as follows:

```
@Document(indexName = "triber-sensor", type = "event")
public class EventDocument implements Event {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private EventMode eventMode;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private EventSubject eventSubject;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String eventId;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private Date creationDate;
}
```

And the spring data repository looks like:

```
public interface EventJpaRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<EventDocument, String> {

    List<EventDocument> findAllOrderByCreationDateDesc(Pageable pageable);

}
```

So I am trying to get all events ordered by creationDate with the newest event first. However when I run the code I get an exception (also in STS):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property desc found for type Date! Traversed path: EventDocument.creationDate.
```

So it seems that it is not picking up the 'OrderBy' part? However a query with a findBy clause (eg findByCreationDateOrderByCreationDateDesc) seems to be okay. Also a findAll without ordering works.
Does this mean that the elastic search module of spring data doesn't allow findAll with ordering?

Comment: The following does work `Page<EventDocument> findAll = eventJpaRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), new Sort(Direction.DESC, "creationDate")));
  return findAll.getContent()`. But i find it very ugly

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **By** to method name:
findAll**By**OrderByCreationDateDesc